# How to align logo to div boundaries while having another element in the same div?

Tags: html, css, alignment, z-index

I am designing a navbar with my school logo in between and an account picture in the right. I want the logo to ignore the account picture div and align to the div. View pictures for more context.

```
|--------logo--------|
|-------logo-------ac|
```

I cannot post a picture because of low reputation points so here is a textual representation

I want the logo to align just like in the first line but with the account picture.

I tried using z-index but it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want the logo to be always centre and the account picture is going to be always at the right most corner, you can do with `position`ing. Check this out below:

```css
header {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header h1 img {
  height: 100px;
}

header .acct {
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <a href=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iP7576O.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
  </h1>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JcFpfoF.jpg" alt="Praveen" class="acct" />
</header>

<p>Here's a comparison for the logo alone centred.</p>

<header>
  <h1>
    <a href=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iP7576O.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
  </h1>
</header>
```

With the above code, you will be able to achieve what you want. Check out the preview.

[image: preview]

The border can be removed and it's shown only for an illustrative purpose.